# Deploy to azure tomcat instance through intellij

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, azure, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure the azure plugin for intellij so that I can deploy my spring project to tomcat directly from my IDE.  I'm sure I'm doing something stupid since I can't get it to work and I can't find ANYTHING as far as directions or other people struggling.

I've tried following the directions listed here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2014/10/27/new-azure-tooling-for-intellij-idea.aspx

These directions lead me to believe that I should be able to set up my project to deploy to my tomcat instance without having to use ftp or any other such method,

Everything goes well for me until I get to the part that says:

> Now that it is ready, we will configure the application to
>   publish/deploy to Azure. With the installation of the Azure plugin,
>   new tools are available to configure and deploy to Azure. Select
>   ‘publish to Azure’.

I'm not sure where I can find the "Publish To Azure" to start the wizard that the final steps talk about.

I have successfully imported my subscription and that seems to be working fine.

Any help to get me past this hurdle would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **EDIT**
Thanks to gapvision I can now see the buttons on my windows machine (not on a MAC)

But I'm having the same problem he is....It hangs during the publish step.  

I'll mark this as closed but hope someone finds it and can enlighten me on this at some point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to display the main toolbar by selecting `View -> Toolbar`.
There you can see the new Azure Tool Buttons.

Comment: I see that now that I put it on a windows machine.  Even selecting this option in a MAC doesn't make it appear.  Sadly:(  '

Comment: Ja seems to be unready at all.. Even in Windows, when I click on deploy nothing happens...

Comment: But after deploying it just hangs while "Waiting for instance"... Thinking about going back to Eclipse, at least for that one...

Comment: I get the same thing.  It just hangs.

Comment: If you want to publish to Azure you first need to create an Azure deployment project. The way to do this is slightly different to the way to do it in Eclipse. First open the project you want to publish, click 'Package for Azure' button (from toolbar -> the little cloud with 2 dots) and the wizard will open. You have to choose a name and directory and then you can select a desired JDK, server and the WAR-files you want to deploy. After you finished this, an Azure project is created and you can now publish this project to Azure via the Publish button.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an second Issue: You can not upload new deployments into an existing CloudService if this CloudService contains Virtual Machines!

It seems that CloudServices containing Virtual Machines and those containing Deployments are very different and can not be combinend into one service.

Therefore, when uploading a new deployment using the Azure Tools for Java, you either have to create a new CloudService or select and existing one without Virtual Machine!

Comment: How in the heck did you figure that out!!??

Comment: @Puttzy playing around, wondering why they speak from "Production" and "Staging" where I didn't see them in my Cloud Services, creating new ones to understand and voila ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have "Publish to Azure" button active new Azure module inside existing project have to be created. Then only this project could be deployed. Anyway, I have faced with another problem when trying to import PUBLISH-SETTINGS file (which is exported from Azure portal). IDEA complains about incorrect format.
Moreover, it's unclear how Azure handles such submitted project together with Tomcat server because folders structure is as follows:

**wwwroot**

-.idea

-bin

--apache-tomcat-7.0.52

---....

---**webapps**

-src

-webapps

-build.gradle

So, as you see deployed (from version control system - bitbucket) project is on wwwroot folder where at the same place is tomcat structure. I haven't found any configuration to set how application should be deployed under tomcat "**webapps**" and not directly under **wwwroot**.